# cargo check: is it possible to show errors before warnings?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

It seems that `cargo check` sort the messages by their relavant line numbers.

But naturally I think errors are more important than warnings, and I'd like to show errors before warnings. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **skip** warnings, until you fix all your errors you can use cargo plugin [cargo-limit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-limit). It provides cargo subcommands, that will show you only errors and provide couple others quality-of-life improvements.

Comment: Note that **I don't recommend this**. Sometimes (perhaps even many times), warnings help finding the real cause of an error, especially if you program without many warnings style.